# Proving Primness in a summation

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I've been hitting my head against the wall for a little bit trying to figure out where to get started on proving (or disproving) the following:

$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that$ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{|k|} i^2 + 2i $ is a prime number$  $

My first instinct tells me that it cannot be prime, due to the fact that for a number like 5, the result would be 35, which is not prime. Could it be I am mis-interpreting the $\exists$? do I only need to prove that a single prime number could exist under the conditions? thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you thought about writing a closed form for the summation?

Comment: The statement is just saying there exists some k for which this produces a prime number, so you need only find one example.

Comment: Your sum gives a prime for $k=\{\pm 1,\pm 2\}$. I highly suspect these are the only solutions.

Comment: Florence of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_and_the_Machine  says tha, while she wears all sorts of outlandish costumes in concerts, in real life she is quite prim.

Comment: @EdwardJiang, -1 is not prime.

Comment: @Genomeme I never said it was...

Comment: @EdwardJiang maybe he just wanted you to know -1 is not prime

Comment: @Oliver: hahahah, thanks. EdwardJiang: I thought -1 yielded -1 in the summation, I just realized |-1|=1 implies only positive values are used for the index i. So -1 yields 3.

Answer (score 2):

$i*i+2i$

$i(i+2)$

$i=1$

$1(1+2)$

$1(3)$

$3$ #is a prime number

Therefore there exists some integer k(1) such that the statement is true

Answer (score 1):

From the original question, you are confused about the things being summed and the sum itself. in particular, $35$ is never considered. The sum comes out
$$ 0,3,11,26,50,85,133,196,\ldots   $$
For a specific $k \geq 0, $ the sum is exactly 
$$ \frac{k(k+1)(2k+7)}{6}.  $$
For $k > 6$ the thing is automatically composite, since the $6$ divides either into one of the factors or $2$ and $3$ do, leaving three factors larger than one. So the thing is prime only for $k=1,2.$

I imagine they are trying to emphasize that a single example is enough to show the truth of existence.